# Array in hidden variable changes to string

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm setting an array to a hidden field using JavaScript. However, the issue is that the array gets converted to a string on form submit when I catch it using PHP.

This is the code that sets the hidden input field value:

```
document.getElementById("hiddenFieldId").value = arrayFromJS;
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Actually the problem is earlier I had a select box which sent it's values nicely on form submit. But now I've got a custom select box using JS which sets comma separated values in a hidden field... So in a nutshell I want that input field to act like a pseudo-select box

Comment: json (encode and decode)

Comment: More code is needed. What is the array you are setting? How are you submitting the form?

Comment: I'd prefer that nothing changes at the server end. I'm submitting the form using POST

Answer (score 1):

You should JSON encode/decode the value:

On the client side you use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to encode the array:

```
document.getElementById("hiddenFieldId").value = JSON.stringify(arrayFromJS);
```

And then on the server side you can use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$arr = json_decode($_POST['hiddenFieldId']); // Fetch the data from POST / GET

foreach ( $arr as $value ) {
    // iterate the array on the server side.
}

unset($arr); // Remember to unset the $arr variable
```

---

If you know you are handeling a simple array (with string only) you can [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the string in javascript and [explode/split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it php:

```
document.getElementById("hiddenFieldId").value = arrayFromJS.join('/:/');
```

PHP:

```
$arr = explode('/:/', $_POST['hiddenFieldId']);
```

---

To support older browser you can use this JSON plugin to the front end: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js